# Get id of link that opened the popup

Tags: javascript, popup

I have a table with column that has a "view" link to view popup. On the popup,
I have a search button I want to get the id of the view link that opened the popup,
when I press search in the popup typically to get some data attributes
associated with each table link..(ex. $this.thisIdopenedMe)

```
<div id="popup" class="popup">
<input type="button" id="searchbtn" onclick="alert($('#smthing??').data("feature"))">
</div>

<table>
<tr> <div id="viewlink" data-feature="alfa" onclick="openPopup("popup")"></div> </tr>
<tr> <div id="viewlink" data-feature="gama" onclick="openPopup("popup")"></div> </tr>
<tr> <div id="viewlink" data-feature="bita" onclick="openPopup("popup")"></div> </tr> ...
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would just use vent delegation and assign more data listeners if you are going to follow the pattern you are using.

```js
var table = document.querySelector("table");
var popUp = document.querySelector("#popup");
var btnSearch = document.querySelector("#searchbtn");

table.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
  var target = event.target;
  var elem = target.closest('[data-feature]');
  if (elem) {
    var selection = elem.dataset.feature;
    popUp.classList.toggle("active");
    btnSearch.dataset.item = selection;
  }
});

btnSearch.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
  console.log(btnSearch.dataset.item);
});
```

```css
.popup {
  display: none;
}


.popup.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="popup" class="popup">
<input type="button" id="searchbtn" value="search">
</div>

<table>
<tr> <td><div id="viewlink" data-feature="alfa">A</div></td></tr>
<tr> <td><div id="viewlink" data-feature="gama">B</div></td></tr>
<tr> <td><div id="viewlink" data-feature="bita">C</div></td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a global variable `selectedFeature` and in your `openPopup` function set that variable to the value of the data attribute so you have it on hand when you need it on search button click.

To get the select element data attribute, you can pass the event from the `onclick` event to your `openPopup` function.

Comment: I have the openpop up logic in separate js file so globar variable gets undefined outside the that js file

Answer (score 0):

```js
function openPopup(div_id, data) {
  popup = document.getElementById(div_id);
  popup.dataset.feature = data;
  console.log(popup.dataset);
}

function showData(div_id) {
  popup = document.getElementById(div_id);
  console.log(popup.dataset.feature);
}
```

```html
<div id="popup" class="popup" data-feature="">
<input type="button" id="searchbtn" onclick="showData('popup')" value="press me">
</div>

<table>

  <tr> 
    <div id="viewlink" data-feature="alfa" onclick="openPopup('popup',this.dataset.feature)">
alfa
    </div> 
  </tr>
  <tr> 
    <div id="viewlink" data-feature="gama" onclick="openPopup('popup',this.dataset.feature)">gama
     </div> 
  </tr>
  <tr> 
    <div id="viewlink" data-feature="bita" onclick="openPopup('popup',this.dataset.feature)">bita
    </div> 
  </tr>
  
</table>
```